# Apache vhosts not working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to set up vhosts on [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) using Apache, but it's seemingly not working.

Output of `apachectl -S`:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 162.210.36.172. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
162.210.36.172:80      xyz.voksul.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/xyz.voksul.net.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

The specific vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost 162.210.36.172:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin xyz@voksul.net
DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html/server
ServerName xyz.voksul.net
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/public_html/server>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>


# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How are you determining it's not working?

Comment: It's loading up /var/www instead of the defined document root for the vhost

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Apache is loading your default configuration. This might be because you've defined the virtual host in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/your-site.conf` but have forgot to symlink it to the `sites-enabled` folder.

Something like `sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/your-site.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` should do the trick .

Comment: That did not fix it. :/ I'm also sure it's symlinked correctly.

Comment: It looks like your domain uses cloudflare. Have you tried testing with this disabled?

Comment: Yes, I don't route the subdomain that i'm trying to get this to work for through cloudflare.. Does Cloudflare's DNS cause issues with vhosts or something?

Comment: Possibly [link](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168616-Why-isn-t-the-direct-subdomain-working-)

Comment: That doesn't help very much.

Comment: Try globbing onto *:80 rather than an IP address, is what I read from that

Comment: I was doing that before - that didn't help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16568/discussion-between-face-and-voidwhisperer).

Answer (score 0):

Does DNS correctly resolve the name to the IP address where Apache is running?

[This guide](http://www.bytelinux.com/enable-apache-virtual-hosting-ubuntu-14-10/) maybe can help you further on configurations.  You can use the a2ensite apache utility to activate the virtual hosts from site-available to sites-enabled, without the need to manually symlink the vhost.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

It **looks** like you've done this, but I wanted to make sure that the relevent vhost config files have the `.conf` suffix.  Apache 2.4 (at least as configured on Ubuntu 14.04) only loads config files ending in `.conf`

On my config, it seemed that renaming the symlinks in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` wasn't sufficient; I had to also rename the files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and update my symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases the problem is related to the naming of default configuration file.
Try to change the name from 000-default.conf to default.conf and add your vhost in a new configuration file.
Greetings